Can an access token be obtained from current logged in org?
Is it possible to obtain an access token from the Salesforce org that a user has currently logged into using a username and password to access an external web application? Have any of you tried this?
I have an org to which I can login to using username and password. From this org, I have to make a REST API call. Can I get access token from this same org?

A Session ID can be used in place of an Access Token (i.e. they are interchangeable), but be aware that a Session ID that originates from Lightning will only have limited API access, as a security precaution. You may also use {!$Api.Session_ID} or {!GETSESSIONID()} in certain contexts (URLs, Visualforce) to get a valid Session ID that you can pass to a third-party service.

It is possible to obtain an access token from a Salesforce org using a username and password to access an external web application.
Refer to this link: https://www.cloudsciencelabs.com/blog/how-to-generate-an-access-token-to-access-salesforce-org

Thank you @Josyula for replying. Can I exchange the user's session Id for an access token?
